# Difference between git push -f vs git push origin +master

Tags: git, repository, git-push

Suppose I want to delete last commit from local and remote repository by `git reset –hard HEAD~`
then
`git push -f` or `git push origin +master`

as *I found both method is used to force push*. Is there any **difference** between above two push command or they worked as same ?

Comment: There is no difference. `git push -f origin branch1 branch2` is equivalent to `git push origin +branch1 +branch2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the manual: `-f` also overrules `--force-with-lease`, plus: the `-f` works on *all* the refs that you push, in case you push multiple at the same time.

Comment: i mean when to use -f or when to use +branch

Comment: If you only push one branch and occasionally want to force push it, the `+` notation is just fine. Neither option is something you would want to use by default though; use with care.